# What is the proper way to encapsulate conditionals in Python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I recently watched a video about good programming practices where the host talked extensively about the danger of using *naked conditionals*, basically non-encapsulated conditionals. The example being that something like this was supposedly preferable to having the condition explicitly written in the `if` statement.

```py
foo = 3 <= len(bar) < 7 and some_other_condition
if foo:
    do_something
    (...)
```

With this information, it would be logical to apply it to while loops the same way.

```py
foo = 3 < len(bar) < 7 and some_other_condition
while foo:
    do_something
    update(some_other_condition)
    (...)
```

The problem here is that the conditional was defined **outside** of the body of the while loop, and it does not update even when the condition is explicitly changed inside the loop.

Another choice would be to define a function that takes care of the conditional and call it each time you iterate. But this (at least to me) seems like unnecessary complexity for the sake of seemingly clean code. Isn't there any way to do this that would not require you define an inner function for each complex conditional?

```py
def foo(x):
    return 3 < len(x) < 7 and some_other_condition

while foo(bar):
    do_something
    update(some_other_condition)
    (...)
```

I haven't been able to find anything on the internet on the topic. So with this in mind, I ask you, what's the **proper** way to encapsulate conditionals in Python?

Comment: Which video did you watch? A couple of lines from The Zen of Python come to mind: "Beautiful is better than ugly" and "Readability counts". I don't think either of these apply to your suggestion

Comment: What were the supposed "dangers"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not at all clear that this technique is preferable, let alone useful or desirable. If nothing else, you are turning one opportunity to make a typo into two.

Just write

```
while 3 < len(x) < y and some_other_condition:
    ...
```

Comment: Also, there are features in the pipeline (like temp variables) that will make the truly horrible conditionals easier to deal with.